# How to create an HTTP POST request, GetRequestStream() causing a WebException: "The underlying connection was closed..."

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, httpwebrequest, http-post

I'm new to C# and .NET and so I'm trying to build a program that sends an HTTP POST request, grabs the response, and writes it to the console. Here's my code:

```
static void Main()
    {
        string uri = "https://api0.ringrevenue.com:3000/api/2010-04-22/calls/1.xml";
        string parameters = "start_time_t=133928918&call_center_call_id=91234567";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = request.GetRequestStream()) // this line gets the error
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            os.Close();
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response == null) Console.WriteLine("Response is null");
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd().Trim());
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error I'm getting is "WebException was unhandled", "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." Any thoughts?

Here's the stack trace:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
at HttpPost.HttpPost.Main() in c:\users\support.qb-server\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\HttpPost.cs:line 24
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: What's the stack trace? Can you post it?

Comment: I get "Unable to connect to the remote server" error. Are you sure that "uri" is correct?

Comment: That uri is being run on localhost:3000, so that might be why you can't replicate it exactly -- just sub in any appropriate URI for uri. Also just uploaded the stack trace.

Comment: [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a must-have for debugging web integration issues.  Can you connect to the url directly by typing it in a web browser?  Do you get any errors when you connect that way to the same url?

Comment: It doesn't support GET requests, only POST, so I do get errors asking for it in a browser, but they're expected.